# Airflow emrAddStepsOperator unable to execute spark shaded jar

Tags: apache-spark, airflow, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, distributed-computing

what should be in step type for spark app .. I am facing issue that master type not set or unable to recognize yarn .. seems it is considering the application as simple jar rather than spark submit mode when using emrAddStepsOperator  .. please find attached airflow dag , error and emr screenshot

[amazon emr cloud console manually adding spark job as a step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Et2t.png)

[After adding spark jar type step rather than custom jar step .. gives option to give spark submit args and main method args separately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEFLX.png)

[step type can be streaming or spark app or custom jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpWT5.png)

My Error  Message:

```
> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:385)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2574)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:934)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:928)
    at com.mcf.ExtractcustomerCategoryWiseSummarizedViews$.main(ExtractcustomerCategoryWiseSummarizedViews.scala:13)
    at com.mcf.ExtractcustomerCategoryWiseSummarizedViews.main(ExtractcustomerCategoryWiseSummarizedViews.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
```

This is an example dag for a AWS EMR Pipeline.

Starting by creating a cluster, adding steps/operations, checking steps and finally when finished
terminating the cluster.

```
import time    
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator     
from datetime import timedelta    

from airflow import DAG    
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.emr_add_steps import EmrAddStepsOperator    
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.emr_create_job_flow import EmrCreateJobFlowOperator    
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.emr_terminate_job_flow import EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator     
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.emr_step import EmrStepSensor    
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago    

SPARK_STEPS = [    
    {    
        'Name': 'PerformETL',    
        'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',    
        'HadoopJarStep': {
            'Jar': 's3://mydata/jars/open-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar',    
            #'MainClass': 'com.sadim.main',    
            'Args': ['spark-submit',    
                    '--deploy-mode',    
                    'cluster',    
                    '--master',    
                    'yarn',    
                    '--class',    
                    'com.sadim.ExtractcustomerCategoryWiseSummarizedViews',     
                    '--mode',    
                'DeltaLoadByDays',    
                '--noOfDaysBehindTodayForDeltaLoad',    
                '1',    
                '--s3InputPath',    
                's3://data-lake/documents/accountscore/categoriseddata/',    
                '--s3OutputPathcustomerCategoryWiseSummarizedViews',    
                's3://test-data/spark_output//customerCategoryWiseSummarizedViews//test'],    
        },
    }
]
SPARK_STEPS2 = [
    {
        'Name': 'sadim_test3',
        'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
        'HadoopJarStep': {
            'Jar': 's3://test-data/jars/scalatestnadeem-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT_v2.jar',
            'MainClass': 'com.sadim.scalatestnadeem.Test',
            'Args': ['spark-submit',    
                '--deploy-mode',    
                'client',    
                '--master',    
                'yarn',    
                '--conf',    
                'spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true'],    
        },    
    }    
]    
SPARK_STEPS3 = [    
    {    
        'Name': 'sadim_test3',    
        'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',    
        'HadoopJarStep': {    
            'Jar': 's3://mydata/jars/open-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT_masteryarnwithoutdependencyandtest.jar',    
            'MainClass': 'com.sadim.TestSadim',    
            'Args': ['spark-submit',     
                '--deploy-mode',    
                'client',     
                '--master',     
                'yarn',    
                '--conf',    
                'spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true'],    
        },    
    }    
]    
SPARK_STEPS4 = [    
    {    
        'Name': 'PerformETL',    
        'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',    
        'HadoopJarStep': {    
            'Jar': 's3://mydata/jars/open-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar',    
            #'MainClass': 'com.sadim.ExtractcustomerCategoryWiseSummarizedViews',    
            'Args': ['com.sadim.ExtractcustomerCategoryWiseSummarizedViews',    
                'spark-submit',    
                '--deploy-mode',    
                'client',    
                 '--master',    
                 'yarn',                    
                    '--mode',    
                'DeltaLoadByDays',    
                '--noOfDaysBehindTodayForDeltaLoad',    
                '1',    
                '--s3InputPath',    
                's3://data-lake/documents/accountscore/categoriseddata/',    
                '--s3OutputPathcustomerCategoryWiseSummarizedViews',    
                's3://test-data/spark_output//customerCategoryWiseSummarizedViews//test'],    
        },    
    }    
]    
SPARK_STEPS5 = [    
    {    
        'Name': 'PerformETL',    
        'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',    
        'HadoopJarStep': {    
            'Jar': 's3://mydata/jars/open-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar',    
            #'MainClass': 'com.sadim.main',    
            'Args': ['com.sadim.ExtractcustomerCategoryWiseSummarizedViews',    
                    '--mode',    
                'DeltaLoadByDays',    
                '--noOfDaysBehindTodayForDeltaLoad',    
                '1',    
                '--s3InputPath',    
                's3://data-lake/documents/accountscore/categoriseddata/',    
                '--s3OutputPathcustomerCategoryWiseSummarizedViews',    
                's3://test-data/spark_output//customerCategoryWiseSummarizedViews//test'],    
        },    
    }    
]    
JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES = {    
    'Name': 'ob_emr_airflow_automation',    
    'ReleaseLabel': 'emr-6.6.0',    
    'LogUri': 's3://test-data/emr_logs/',    
    'Instances': {    
        'InstanceGroups': [    
            {    
                'Name': 'Master node',    
                'Market': 'ON_DEMAND',    
                'InstanceRole': 'MASTER',    
                'InstanceType': 'm5.xlarge',    
                'InstanceCount': 1    
            },    
            {    
                    'Name': "Slave nodes",    
                    'Market': 'ON_DEMAND',
                    'InstanceRole': 'CORE',    
                    'InstanceType': 'm5.xlarge',    
                    'InstanceCount': 1    
            }    
        ],    
        'Ec2SubnetId': 'subnet-03129248888a14196',    
        'Ec2KeyName': 'datalake-emr-nodes',    
        'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': True,    
        'TerminationProtected': False    
    },    
    'BootstrapActions': [    
                {    
                        'Name': 'Java11InstallBootstrap',    
                        'ScriptBootstrapAction': {    
                            'Path': 's3://test-data/jars/bootstrap.sh',    
                            'Args': [    
                            ]    
                        }    
                }    
    ],    
    'Configurations': [    
        {    
            "Classification":"spark-defaults",    
                    "Properties":{    
                    "spark.driver.defaultJavaOptions":"-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' -    XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70",    
                    "spark.executor.defaultJavaOptions":"-verbose:gc -Xlog:gc*::time -    XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions"
                                }    
        }    
    ],    
    'JobFlowRole': 'DL_EMR_EC2_DefaultRole',    
    'ServiceRole': 'EMR_DefaultRole',    
}    

with DAG(    
    dag_id='emr_job_flow_manual_steps_dag_v6',    
    default_args={    
        'owner': 'airflow',    
        'depends_on_past': False,    
        'email': ['sadim.nadeem@sadim.com'],    
        'email_on_failure': False,    
        'email_on_retry': False,    
    },    
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=1),    
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    schedule_interval='0 3 * * *',
    tags=['example'],
) as dag:

    # [START howto_operator_emr_manual_steps_tasks]
    cluster_creator = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
        task_id='create_job_flow',
        job_flow_overrides=JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES,
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        emr_conn_id='emr_default',
    )

    delay_python_task: PythonOperator = PythonOperator(task_id="delay_python_task",
                                                   dag=dag,
                                                   python_callable=lambda: time.sleep(400))

    step_adder = EmrAddStepsOperator(
        task_id='add_steps',
        job_flow_id=cluster_creator.output,
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        steps=SPARK_STEPS5,
    )

    step_checker = EmrStepSensor(
        task_id='watch_step',
        job_flow_id=cluster_creator.output,
        step_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='add_steps', key='return_value')[0] }}",
       aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    )

    cluster_remover = EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator(
        task_id='remove_cluster',
        job_flow_id=cluster_creator.output,
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    )

    cluster_creator >> step_adder >> step_checker >> cluster_remover

    # [END howto_operator_emr_manual_steps_tasks]

    # Task dependencies created via `XComArgs`:
    #   cluster_creator >> step_checker
    #   cluster_creator >> cluster_remover
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got fixed. We need to use the command-runner jar as jar option in emrAddStepsOperator and pass your specific ETL job jar inside args as

```
SPARK_STEPS = [
    {
        'Name': 'DetectAndLoadOrphanTransactions',
        'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
        'HadoopJarStep': {
            'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
            #'MainClass': 'com.sadim.main',
            'Args': [ 
            'spark-submit',
            '--deploy-mode',
                'cluster',
                 '--master',
                 'yarn',
                 '--class',
                    'com.sadim.DetectAndLoadOrphanTransactions',
                 's3://nadeem-test-data/jars/open-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT_yarn_yarndep_maininpom.jar',
                '--Txnspath',
                's3://nadeem-test-data/spark_output//CategorizedTxnsDataset//2022_load_v2',
                '--demographyPath',
                's3://nadeem-test-data/spark_output//customerDemographics//2022_load_v2'
                '--outPath',
                's3://nadeem-test-data/spark_output//orphan_ihub_ids//2022_load_v2'],
        },
    }
]
```